# vb count Strange Behavior

Tags: vb.net

I am getting a wierd error when trying to use Count as a lambda

> 'Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer' Has no parameters and its
>   return type cannot be indexed'

If i **Count** to **LongCount** it magically works. According to [this blog post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/34a66c1f-81d4-4f6f-bab5-2a0be64db1ec/) 3 years ago this was a known issue. It seems it still is. **My question is how do i resolve this issue?**

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()

        Dim wit2 As New List(Of TestCount) From {New TestCount With {.title = "foo" _
                                                                 ,.PartNumber = "bar"} _ 
                                                 , New TestCount With {.title = "chuck" _
                                                               , .PartNumber = "norris"}}                                          
        Console.WriteLine(wit2.Count(Function(x) x.title = "chuck"))
    End Sub
    Friend Class TestCount
        Property title As String
        Property PartNumber As String
    End Class
End Module
```

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever fixed the quote error

Comment: Also, on the question you've linked to, one of the answers says "One workaround is to call .AsEnumerable() before applying the .Count() extension method." - does that workaround not work for you?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it does, I am curious if there is a way of importing/adding a reference without casting the list to enumerable

Comment: It doesn't cost anything to call [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb335435.aspx): "The `AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` method has no effect other than to change the compile-time type of source from a type that implements `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` itself."

Comment: To this day, this still seem to be a problem in VB.Net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
wit2.Where(Function(elem) elem.title="chuck").Count()
```

It is much simpler than above one.

hope it will help

List has both the Count property defined in the List class, and the Count() extension method defined on IEnumerable.  This may seem redundant, but keep in mind that not all IEnumerable implementations have a count defined.

As any collection that implements ICollection or ICollection must specify a Count property.  Since List, arrays, and many other collections implement ICollection, this means call Count directly and avoid calling the extension method.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will use the AsEnumerable().Count fix the article described. But your explanation on why it is makes it clearer. I chose to use the AsEnumerable because i think it is more readable with the count closer to the start of the command then the end.

Comment: What is better for performance? `AsEnumarable.Count(expression)` or `Where(expression).Count()`

Comment: AsEnumarable.Count(expression) as where expression will be internally called. but quick question where are you getting this kind of performance hit